# How do I get 100% game completion while offline?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

Do i need to be playing online to get the 100% game completion in red dead redemption? I want to get my last outfit, but it says to get 100% completion and i know how to get it. I have completed all the master challenges and story missions, along with the stranger tasks, but my completion is still only 98.5%. How do I get 100% game completion?

Comment: What does your social club stats look like? http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/rdr/checklist

Comment: my internet isnt up atm, so i can't get into the social club

Comment: Huh.. how are you posting this message then?

Comment: @JamesJiao Mobile site? Posting from work/school/library/starbucks instead of at home where the console on which he plays RDR is? Could be any number of answers.

Comment: my ps3 wont connect to the internet. I'm at a mates place

Comment: it actually needed to be connected to the internet to get 100% game completion in RDR?

Comment: OK I see what the problem is now. Can you please go to this link and tell me how many of each you have? http://www.trueachievements.com/viewcomment.aspx?commentid=285930#vch

Comment: I done them all but the bounties... i think. Are the challenges it refers to the master hunter etc?

Comment: @TazFlame Well yes, it is included. It says that in the solution. It also gives you the link to all the challenges. http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Single_Player_Challenges#Single_Player_Challenges Just ignore the DLC ones.

Comment: so i have to get 20 bounties, along with all those other things to get 100% game completion?

Comment: @TazFlame Please read the link I gave you. It is the SOLUTION for getting 100% in the game. There are 13 outfits in this game without DLCs. 9 are needed for 100% and 4 are not. The ones that are needed and how to get them are all in the solution.

Comment: Ok. Thanks heaps for your patience with me :) I'm gonna go home and finish this game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly, highly, highly suggest using the [RDR Social Club](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/rdr/checklist), even if you just create an account to view the "100% Completion" page.  The 100% completion page lists everything you need in order to get 100%, and if at any point you can get online for even a few moments, it will auto-update with the latest status from your game, if your Social Club account is linked to your PSN or Xbox Live IDs.

If you are missing an item, you can typically hover over it to get a quick tip as to what it is specifically that you need to do.

Failing that, you can use the [100% completion checklist](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/100%25_Completion) on the Red Dead Wikia.  It lists all of the things you need to do with links to Wikia articles on the best/easiest way to get them.

For reference, the things that count towards 100% are:

- 57 story missions
- 5 rare weapons
- 5 side jobs (horse breaking & night watch)
- 9 outfits (although there are more in-game, the DLC ones do not count)
- 13 owned houses (rentals do not count)
- 7 gang hideout missions (must complete at least once)
- 8 ambient challenges (all must be at rank 10)
- 18 strangers (all except "I Know You" which is missable - this includes "Remember My Family" which is only available *after* the main story arc is complete)
- 6 mini games (win at all forms of gambling, essentially - you must leave the mini game having won money)
- 94 map locations (it counts if you buy maps at shops)

There's no requirement to be online, or to play the multiplayer mode for even a second to get 100%.  Undead Nightmare has its own 100% completion award, and is tracked separately.